# Varnish not ignoring subdomain despite vcl rules

Tags: apache, caching, reverse-proxy, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am running a basic lamp server with apache on port 80, and varnish on port 81. I am attempting to exclude a subdomain of the primary site entirely, however I have had no luck in doing so thus far, and I'm not sure why.

As you can see below, I have a rule in place to A) skip logged in users on the subdomain, and B) skip the subdomain entirely. Neither of these seem to work however. Is there something wrong with my vcl configuration?

```
backend default {
.host = "my.server.ip.address";
.port = "80";
}



sub vcl_recv {
call identify_device;

    # Allow the back-end to serve up stale content if it is responding slowly.
    set req.grace = 2m;

    # Always cache the following file types for all users.
    if ( req.url ~ "(?i)\.(png|gif|jpeg|jpg|ico|swf|css|js|html|htm)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$" ) {
            unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    # Don't serve cached pages to logged in users
    if ( req.http.cookie ~ "wordpress_logged_in" || req.url ~ "vaultpress=true" ) {
            return( pass );
    }

    #Lets skip the logged in users on subdomain too!
    if ( req.http.cookie ~ "dmr_user" ) {
    return (pass);
    }

    #skip subdomain.domain.com
    if (req.http.host ~ "subdomain.domain.com") {
    return (pass);
    }

    #Following for WooCommerce and comments
    if (req.url ~ "^/(cart|my-account|checkout|addons|wp-comments-post)") {
    return (pass);
    }

    #Lets skip the logged in users on entries too!
    if ( req.http.cookie ~ "dmr_user" ) {
    return (pass);
    }

    if ( req.url ~ "\?add-to-cart=" ) {
     return (pass);
     }

    # Drop any cookies sent to WordPress.
    if ( ! ( req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)" ) ) {
            unset req.http.cookie;
    }        

}

sub vcl_fetch {


if (beresp.ttl < 180s) {
set beresp.ttl = 180s;
}
    if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
            unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

}

sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.http.X-Device);
}


sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
            set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
    } else {
            set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only skipping the processing of the subdomain halfway into your handling, ie instructions are executed in order.  Moving  the skip domain check directly at the top of sub vcl_recv should ensure no other rules gets executed against requests to that subdomain.

Comment: Excellent call @marcel! So simple. If it works I may have to go soak my head. I'll be testing in just a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Well guys, it turns out that what I needed was to use pipe instead of pass.

```
#skip subdomain.domain.com
if (req.http.host ~ "subdomain.domain.com") {
return (pass);
}
```

is now

```
#skip subdomain.domain.com
if (req.http.host ~ "subdomain.domain.com") {
return (pipe);
}
```

I also went ahead and moved it up to the top of the config. Altogether it works like a charm now. Thanks to everyone for their help!